# Reordering animation in SwiftUI grid

Tags: ios, animation, swiftui

I try to animate the reordering of elements in a grid, unfortunately I have to build the grid by myself (two `ForEach`) because LazyVGrid is only available in iOS 14, and our app has to support iOS 13 as well :(

Shuffling the rows or the columns would be animated, but how to animate individual elements moving

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var elements = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
    
    @State var columns = [0, 1]
    
    @State var rows: [Int] = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(rows, id: \.self) { i in
                HStack {
                    ForEach(columns, id: \.self) { j in
                        Text("element\(elements[2 * i + j])")
                    }
                }
            }
            
            Button("Randomize") {
                self.elements.shuffle()
            }
        }.animation(.default)
    }
    
}
```